# How do I save an HTML table edited with jQuery to local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offline

I have an html table that a user can add individual rows to. I would like the user to be able to save this offline so that the data on the table stays after a refresh. I have been told this is the easiest way but if anyone has any other suggestions I have open ears.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 1;
var table = "You fucked up yo";
$('#add').click(function addRow(){
  var model = $('#Model').val();
  var size = $('#Size').val();
  var resolution = $('#Resolution').val();
  var backlight = $('#Backlight').val();
  var pins = $('#Pins').val();
  var touch = $('#Touch').val();
  $('#screens').append("<tr id='row"+count+"'><td>"+count+"</td><td id 
  ='model"+count+"'>"+model+"</td><td id ='sizes"+count+"'>"+size+"</td><td 
  id 
  ='resolution"+count+"'>"+resolution+"</td><td id 
  ='backlight"+count+"'>"+backlight+"</td><td id ='pins"+count+"'>"+pins+"
  </td><td id ='touch"+count+"'>"+touch+"</td>");
  var key = "table"+count;
  count++;
});
$('#remove').click(function removeRow(){
  var row = $('#row').val();
  $('table#screens tr#row'+row).remove();
});
$('#save').click(function save(){
  var table = $('#screens').html;
  localStorage.setItem("Table", table);
  alert('yo');
});
$('#open').click(function open(){
  $('#screens').html =  localStorage.getItem("Table");
  alert('yo');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to solve this would be using a JSON to store your table values and just storing that structure in localStorage or database. But to answer your question I think this is what you need to store and retrieve the table structure from localStorage. Hope this is what you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="tablediv"></div>

<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("Mytable", "<table><tr><td>col1</td></tr></table>");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("tableDiv").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Mytable");
} else {
    document.getElementById("tableDiv").innerHTML = "Your browser does not support Web Storage";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. Be sure to use JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() as follows:

```
var tableData = [{name: "John", email: "jhenry@example.com"}];
// Persist
localStorage.setItem("nameForYourData", JSON.stringify(tableData));
// Retrieve
tableData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("nameForYourData"));
```

Comment: Can I not just use var tableData = $(#myTable).html; for the first line instead?

Comment: That would store the html, not the data.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this i think:

```
var table = $('table').wrap('<table/>').parent().html();
table = JSON.stringify(table);
window.localStorage.setItem('savedTable', table);

// then later
table = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('savedTable'))
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8dhnqy0b/